# How does geolite region codes works?

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolite2

We are using the region code from Geolite (Maxmind) that we found here: http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/misc/region_codes.csv

Does anyone know how they select the region they cover? I'm asking because for Latvia (LV) we cannot find any logical reason for those regions. There also are duplicated entries and entries which are exactly the same but with an s at the end.

If anyone already used them and know the reason, it would be very helpfull. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [FIPS 10-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_10-4) region codes. Looking at [Latvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_region_codes_(J%E2%80%93L)#LG:_Latvia), it appears that the distinction between "Municipality" and "District" got lost in MaxMind's data.

Comment: Now that I know what those regions are, I understand why I could not find any connection with the region we use. Those regions are the administrative regions from before the Administrative territorial reform of Latvia from 2009 and I use the one from after! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, the US government has stopped maintaining FIPS. MaxMind now uses ISO 3166-2 in its GeoLite2/GeoIP2 products and only uses FIPS in its legacy products.